# In SSRS Report Builder, the results that are being delivered are in a very long string, I need to be able to extract certain substrings

Tags: sql, reporting-services

One result, under one field of data contains the below, it's extremely long. I need to be able to pull out certain substrings into seperate columns.

Desired Result:

1) email addresses that it's being sent to, identified by "TO": gregory.dettorre@cardinalhealth.com; scott.ballard@cardinalhealth.com

2) email addresses that it's being CC'd to, identified by "CC":
GMB-OptiFreight-CCBABR@cardinalhealth.com

3) email addresses that it's being CC'd to, identified by "ReplyTo":
OptiFreightcustomercare@cardinalhealth.com

4) Include report: True

5) Render Format: Excel

6) Subject: 13 Week Volume File - LifePoint Health - Brentwood, TN

Result:

```
"<ParameterValues><ParameterValue><Name>TO</Name>
<Value>gregory.dettorre@cardinalhealth.com; 
scott.ballard@cardinalhealth.com</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue>
<Name>CC</Name><Value>GMB-OptiFreight-CCBABR@cardinalhealth.com</Value>
</ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>ReplyTo</Name>
<Value>OptiFreightcustomercare@cardinalhealth.com</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>IncludeReport</Name><Value>True</Value>
</ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>RenderFormat</Name>
<Value>EXCEL</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>Subject</Name>
<Value>13 Week Volume File - LifePoint Health - Brentwood, TN</Value>
</ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>Comment</Name><Value>Please see the 
attached 13 week volume file and let us know if you have any questions.

OptiFreightcustomercare@cardinalhealth.com</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>False</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>Priority</Name><Value>NORMAL</Value></ParameterValue></ParameterValues>"
```

Comment: Can you use an xpath query in SSRS? `/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name='TO']/Value` will return you all the TO values

Comment: xpath on the server side is the way to go. Don;t try to do this with SSRS expressions.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1413824-150-1.aspx) there is an answered question on splitting strings, using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX in SSRS. You Get the indexes of 2 delimiters (e.g. "TO" and "CC"), and by applying SUBSTRING between these 2 delimiters you get the value that you wanted.

Also, the best practice would probably be splitting the data in the dataset (e.g. SQL query) itself, instead of doing so in the report itself.